# Ignore files in a Project to a Fork in Github

Tags: github, gitignore

I want to ignore some files from a project in Github, so they don't show on my fork.

ex: README.md in another language which I won't use/update, to not show on my project when I Fork it.

Is that possible?

Answer (score -1):

Add that file or directory to your `.gitignore` file in the root directory and make sure to commit the file.